# the meaning of 'borrowed plumes'

Tags: phrase-meaning

> They pity no one. They answer to no one. Their lives are simple. When
>   they look down they see nothing but their prey, and the **borrowed
>   plumes** of the hunters: they see a flittering, flinching universe, a
>   universe filled with their dinner.
>
> — Bring Up the Bodies by Hilary Mantel

This is a scene of hawking. What is the "**borrowed plumes**"? I googled it and all I got is an idiom meaning "empty pretensions" which I don't think applies here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this sentence uses 'borrowed plumes' in its literal sense.  A plume is a feather or arrangement of feathers used for decoration.  A borrowed plume is a plume being worn by someone other than the bird that grew it.

I'm not sure if 'hunters' refers to the humans, the other falcons or both.  Falconers put hoods on the birds when they're on the glove, and these hoods have little feather plumes on top.  But during this time period, humans also liked to wear feathers in their hats, and a few paragraphs later the book says that Henry was wearing a hat with a black plume.

The falcon looks down from the sky and sees the hunters from above, so the only part of them visible would be their hats, which are decorated with borrowed plumes.